# Magento custom form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, magento, prototype

I have Magento version 1.7.0.2 Billing Checkout form 2 inputs type="checkbox".

My HTML for checkbox1:

```
<span class="field-row" id="checkbox1">

<div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="validate-checkboxgroup-required validation-failed"
                name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox1][]" id="checkbox1___385" value="385">&nbsp;Value1
    </div>
</div><div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"  name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox1][]" id="checkbox1___384" value="384">&nbsp;Value2
    </div>
</div><div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"  name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox1][]" id="checkbox1___383" value="383">&nbsp;Value3
    </div>
</div>
</span>
```

And Checkbox2:

```
<span class="field-row" id="checkbox2">

<div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" class="validate-checkboxgroup-required validation-failed"
                name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox2][]" id="checkbox2___385" value="385">&nbsp;Value4
    </div>
</div><div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"  name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox2][]" id="checkbox2___384" value="384">&nbsp;Value5
    </div>
</div><div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"  name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox2][]" id="checkbox2___383" value="383">&nbsp;Value6
    </div>
</div>
</span>
```

How can I make a javascript form validation to test if at least one checkbox (with many boxes) is checked.

I have created a jQuery event on submit Button to prevent submission:

```
    function nbOfCheckedBoxes(spanId) {
        var selected = [];
        jQuery("#"+spanId+" input:checked").each(function () {
            selected.push(jQuery(this).attr('name'));
        });
        return selected.length;
    }

jQuery( "#billing-buttons-container button" ).click(function(e) {
    if(nbOfCheckedBoxes('checkbox1')==0 && nbOfCheckedBoxes('checkbox2')==0)  {
        //alert( "NOT OK" );
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    });
```

but it doesn't work. Any Ideas ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? It worked for me. Can you elaborate its actual behavior at your end? Check carefully if there are js conflict with other scripts and you have jquery library included.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using the module "Customer Attributes by Amasty" https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-attributes-by-amasty.html  and try to customise it. The css class "validate-checkboxgroup-required" have I added by on Form Submit, and that don't work on the first submit, on only on the second one.